# How to pass client id of Item in repeater to javascript

Tags: asp.net

I need to pass div client id to JavaScript of a repeater

I have 3 divs inside a repeater i have onmouseover event i want to grab client id of div element Is there any way i can pass exact client of div element

Can u guys help me out Thanks

Comment: Could you please show the code you have so far? It will make things more clear.

Comment: Might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641280/reference-asp-net-control-by-id-in-javascript see the second answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this (if I understood you correctly):

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="myDiv" runat="server">......</div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl myDiv = e.Item.FindControl("myDiv") as HtmlGenericControl;
        // you can just pass "this" instead of "myDiv.ClientID" and get the ID from the DOM element
        myDiv.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "doStuff('" + myDiv.ClientID + "');");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you would like to do it in markup, you can use 
the following to get the ClientId:

```
<%# Container.FindControl("_RepeaterEL").ClientID %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="modal hide fade" ID="myModal" runat="server">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                                <h3>Add to cart</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <nav>
                                    <iframe seamless src="/ToCart/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "code")%>"
                                        style="border-style: none;"> </iframe>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
</asp:Panel>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#<%#Container.FindControl("myModal").ClientID%>">
    <div class="add-to-cart-one">+</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the repeater renders to the browser, you can get the repeater element with:

```
var rep = $get("<%= rpt.ClientID %>");
```

Otherwise, wrap a

```
<DIV id="RepeaterEL"></div>
```

around the repeater, and access its children either through pure JavaScript (and the childNodes collection), or using JQuery like

```
$("#RepeaterEL").children("DIV").each(function(i) {    
   var id = $(this).attr("id"); //<- pointer to DIV });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567040/asp-controls-id-generation-inside-repeater i have same problem is there any way i can pass client id to javascript