# Update Repeater Textbox with KeyUp Event of another Textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

Hello i have one Repeater Control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCashCome" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrencyNo" onkeyup="javascript:CallFunction()" CssClass="mws-textinput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="True" ID="txtTotal" CssClass="mws-textinput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
```

I have a Jquery Function

```
function CallFunction() {

//code here i want something like. txtCurrencyNo* 500 = txtTotal
// something like calculative here. but how will i find the Control ID of repeater ?



 }
```

This function is Called. but how do i do calculation based on textbox KeyUp ? how will i find the control ID here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can user jQuery for this.
use

```
$(this).val()
```

It will give you the value of the current text box.
If the other text box is in the same template then you can use like this (not tested)

```
function CallFunction() {
    var firstTextBoxVal= $(this).val();
    $(this).next().val(firstTextBoxVal* 500 )
}
```

change your repeater as follows

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCashCome" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrencyNo" onkeyup="javascript:CallFunction(this)" CssClass="mws-textinput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="True" ID="txtTotal" CssClass="mws-textinput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: and how to set it to another textbox ?

Comment: and i am not getting value by this.

Comment: Its not working. Its in same template.and even the setting is not happening.

Comment: I really appreciate your help shekhar. but its not working :( neither its getting the value nor it is setting value

Comment: put simple alert inside your function and let me know weather it is working or not

Comment: yes thats working fine.I will get the value somehow. the main prob is how do i set the value

Comment: I did not able to solve the problem but But you can go through this link to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796514/how-to-pass-client-id-of-item-in-repeater-to-javascript